# password_verify returning false even though correct

Tags: php

Hi I am testing using bcrypt with php after using it with node.js and am finding some trouble with my code. Essentially I am typing in a username and a password into a form and this is hashing and echoing the hash onto the page and it also is running a password verify and is supposed to return a message saying the password is correct if it is correct, but it is not returning true ever.

Here is my code (note there is no use of a database and this code should always mean the $password is equal to the $hash)

```
<?php
$username = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];



$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) . "<br/>";

echo $hash; 


if (password_verify($password , $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

This is returning the has and invalid password as such":

"$2y$10$yzY0md5wm3nBZvuynPV7mO2W3Ux9455AG/dWfLzwEqRtC1DfMx9Oa
Invalid password."

Comment: You concatenated "<br/>" to the hash. So, it shouldn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) . "<br/>";
```

to

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```